# Running a Clang LibTooling tool over an iOS Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, clang, llvm-clang

I've written a toy libtooling based tool that does some analysis/source rewriting over ObjectiveC code. How do I run it over an iOS Xcode project?

I've looked at [compiling the application through commandline/clang](http://commandlinefanatic.com/cgi-bin/showarticle.cgi?article=art024), but I haven't got it to work yet. Is it possible to chain my tool  with xcodebuild? Or is there a better way to run the tool over an Xcode project?

Comment: Do you need this tool to run before your code compiles? What does it needs as input?

Comment: It needs to run before compilation, I'd like to rewrite the source before compilation. The tool needs the source files and should be able to construct an AST for the app - which means fixing up all the framework linking issues, unless I'm taking the wrong approach to this.

Comment: did you ever make this work @Sorcerer13?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is [JSON-Compilation-Database](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html).

You can use [xctool](https://github.com/facebook/xctool) to generate a json compilation databse (xctool has a reporter that generate this thing, see the readme.)

The json compilation database is just a json file which contains all the compiler options (say, the header search path, the frame work search path) that need to pass to the clang and libtooling based tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your tool to generate errors and warnings in code it should be a clang plugin and you can just change your project clang flags to load the plugin.

In your case it seems like you are using libtooling that alters the source code, you can simply add your script to your project build process prior to the "Compile Sources" stage.

1. In Xcode -> Click on Project ->  click on your desired Target -> Build Phases -> Click on Editor (Menu Bar) -> Add Build Phase -> Add Run Script
2. Drag the new Run Script to be before Compile Sources
3. Edit the run script phase to do what you want

Comment: The tool needs to create the AST for the code to enable refactoring - I haven't figured out the magic to fix all the framework/header issues yet. Wouldn't using a run script encounter the same type of issues?

I used libtooling over a clang plugin as it seemed libtooling was better suited for refactoring, which is the end goal - I'm not really biased either ways. I'll look at it again, thanks.